# Diffeomorphism between an ellipse and unit circle?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to learn about diffeomorphism and an example asks for a diffeomorphism between an ellipse and an unit circle.

How does one construct such?

Comment: Use a invertible $2$-by-$2$ diagonal matrix as the diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a specific ellipse, and presumably the person asking the question would not accept the unit circle as an example of an ellipse (in which case the identity mapping would deliver).

I would suggest using the standard equation of an ellipse with horizontal and vertical axes, centered on the origin. This is a scaled version of the unit circle with possibly different scaling factors in the horizontal and vertical directions. Scaling back provides an example of a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Define $T(x,y) = (x,2y).$ Verify that $T$ maps the unit circle bijectively onto the ellipse $u^2 + v^2/4=1.$